# Scope issues with Qt Quick and C++ classes

Tags: c++, qt, udp, qml

I have a project that I am working on, that will hopefully result in C++ code with a QML UI as a console, communicating with other consoles and equipment.
My test setup is based on a RaspBerry Pi running UDP comms (works fine into a normal Qt application).
I have tried to port to Qt Quick, and use a simple QML UI, but if I declare the subclass early in my "main.cpp" it doesn't connect properly.
If I declare it in the main.cpp  "main" function, then I have scope issues with the subclass functions that I want to use to transfer data.
Open to suggestions / critique......and I am 100% sure that there is a "proper" way of doing this, so if anyone wants to point me at it......I will be enraptured!

Qt version is Qt5.3.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 440; height: 150
    color: "orange"


    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent; spacing: 20

        Text {
            text: rootItem.theChange
            font.pointSize: 12; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        }
    }
}

// signalgrab.h
#ifndef SIGNALGRAB_H
#define SIGNALGRAB_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QString>

class SignalGrab : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    explicit SignalGrab(QObject *parent = 0);
    int SendValue();
    void setupUDP();

    signals:

    public slots:
    void readyRead();

    private:
    QUdpSocket *socket;
    QHostAddress groupAddress;
};

#endif // SIGNALGRAB_H

// signalgrab.cpp

#include "signalgrab.h"

int i3 = 0;

SignalGrab::SignalGrab(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)

{
    // create a QUDP socket
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

    socket->bind(QHostAddress("0.0.0.0"), 45454);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    qDebug() << "Socket connected ok!";
}

void SignalGrab::readyRead()
{
    // when data comes in
    QByteArray buffer;
    buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(),
                         &sender, &senderPort);

    std::string s1 (buffer);
    std::string s2 = s1.substr(26,sizeof(s1));

    i3 = atoi(s2.data());

    SendValue();
}

int SignalGrab::SendValue()
{

    qDebug() << "sending i3 as:  "<< i3;
    return i3;
}

// main.cpp

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>

#include <QString>
#include "signalgrab.h"

int y=13;

// ///////////////////////////////////
//SignalGrab nc;
// ///////////////////////////////////

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString theChange READ getTheChange NOTIFY changeOfStatus)

public:
    Object()
    {
        changeMe = false;
        myTimer = new QTimer(this);
        myTimer->start(5000);
        connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(testSlot()));
    }

    QString getTheChange()
    {
        if (theValue == 0)
        {
            return "The Acid QML Test";
        }
        if (theValue == 1)
        {
            y = (fetchValue());

            qDebug() << "New y!" << y;
            return  QString("Returning %1").arg(y);
        }
        return "nothing has happened yet";
    }


    int fetchValue()
    {
        //  return (nc::SendValue());
        return y;
    }



    Q_INVOKABLE void someFunction(int i)
    {
        if ( i == 0) {
            theValue = 0;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            theValue = 1;
        }
        emit changeOfStatus(i);
    }


signals:
    void changeOfStatus(int i) ;

public slots:
    void testSlot()
    {
        if (changeMe)
        {
            someFunction(0);
        } else {
            someFunction(1);
        }
        changeMe = !changeMe;
    }

private:
    bool changeMe;
    int theValue;
    QTimer *myTimer;
};


#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Object myObj;

    // //////////////////////////////
    SignalGrab nc;           //added
    // //////////////////////////////

    nc.SendValue();

    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootItem", (QObject *)&myObj);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The uploaded code runs, but does not update the value for "y" in main.cpp. as it is commented out in the function "fetchValue()".  If the "return y;" line is commented out instead, then the scope error occurs.  I am sure I am doing something silly or at best clumsy....

Comment: I got this working...as I said it was a silly/clumsy error.  I copied a line of code to the area BEFORE Q_OBJECT, instead of after....oops. Once I resolve that, the scope issues magically disappeared.  I shall wear my dunces cap for today, but my RasPi now talks to both Linux and Win7 UIs in QML.....so I can move on to the next stage of my project!   :-)